# Why brackets are necessary in catch block in java?

Tags: java, syntax, braces, catch-block

In java if we have to execute only one statement after `if` or `for` the brackets are not necessary. We can write:

```
if(condition)
  executeSingleStatement();
```

or

```
for(init;condition;incr)
  executeSingleStatement();
```

But in the case of catch block why we can not omit the brackets? Why this is not possible?

```
catch(Exception e)
   e.printStackTrace();
```

Because in most of the case <del>we</del> I have only one statement in catch block which is either `e.printStackTrace()` while testing or logging statement.

Comment: a method needs curlies even for a one statement method as well. Perhaps it's because there's an implicit   e = thrownException; as the first statement in the catch block.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: What does `e = thrownException;` means? We are declaring `e` as an Exception in the parameter block then why does this statement is needed?

Comment: @Harry Joy: Think about it. How does 'e' get to contain the exception object?

Comment: @Gkelly , @MeBigFatGuy : So it will first initialize `e` with the exception that has occurred and then do the rest processing. Am I right?

Comment: As a side note: Another interesting case is where you not have any body at all like `if(condition);` (notice the semicolon at the end)

Comment: *Because in most of the case we have only statement in catch block which is either e.printStackTrace() while testing or logging statement.* I do like being included in the `we` part, poor exception handling is just poor exception handling.

Comment: There is a significant difference between a *statement* and a *block*.  A statement is simply that -- a sequence of executable operations.  A block includes context -- conceptually it is a miniature method body, and can have its own local declarations, etc.  This actually is an important distinction for exception handling at several levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an issue of possible or impossible. It's just a language (syntax) design decision.

There are several implementation of Java language parser. One could modify the parser source less than a day and allow no-bracket-enclosed catch statements.

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+parser

Also note [Java language grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html).

Answer (score 10):

Find a compiler construction textbook and look-up the *dangling-else ambiguity*.

Given that in Java, and most other languages with horrible syntax, spacing lies. How do you interpret:

```
try
try
stuff();
catch (FooException exc)
handle(exc);
catch (BarException exc)
handle(exc);
catch (BazException exc)
handle(exc);
```

Is it:

```
try {
    try {
        stuff();
    } catch (FooException exc) {
        handle(exc);
    } catch (BarException exc) {
        handle(exc);
    }
} catch (BazException exc) {
    handle(exc);
}
```

Or:

```
try {
    try {
        stuff();
    } catch (FooException exc) {
        handle(exc);
    }
} catch (BarException exc) {
    handle(exc);
} catch (BazException exc) {
    handle(exc);
}
```

The dangling-else ambiguity is resolved by associating the `else` with the inner-most `if`. Do we want to add a more complicated complication to handle this poor style? No.

**Edit:** There's a comment that the example does not cover `catch`. It would be a *proper* **weird** decision to require braces on `try` but not `catch`/`finally`. But anyway, for completeness, consider the following code.

```
try {
stuff();
} catch (FooException foo)
try {
handle(foo);
} catch (BarException bar)
handle(bar);
catch (BazException baz)
handle(baz);
finally
release();
```

Is the `catch` of `BazException` and `finally` associated with the inner or outer `try`? Again the language design committee could have added a ton of grammar to disambiguate, but again explicit style wins. My job at Sun/Oracle would have been a little easier if the language had been simplified to mandate explicit braces everywhere.

Comment: Your answer perfectly explains why we need brackets for try but I am still unclear with the need of brackets with catch statement

Comment: Your explaination uses poor style as a reason, which if it was the actual reason for the language designer they wouldn't have stopped there

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why Java doesn't allow that but generally speaking it is better style to use brackets even if there is only one statement. It makes it easier to read and expand.

Here is a related question that addresses whether to use brackets or not: [Are curly braces necessary in one-line statements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java Language Spec 3.0](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf) - If you look at Chapter 14, it talks about Blocks and  Statements. Blocks are identified by { and } and contain many statements. Try/catch/finally are blocks, which per the language spec need to be grouped in { }.

Comment: I think your answer can be elaborated, but your on to something. The same applies for a lot of other commands. For instance, does the class { } require brackets or not (is e.g. "class int no;" also valid?)

Comment: I know that catch requires brackets (as per Java Spec) but I want to know the reason why it is required?

Comment: How come this gets +2? You can't explain the rule with the rule itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also do not see any benefit in writing useless code and I also do not understand how more text could be easier.

I help myself by writing one-line-catches in exactly one line:

```
catch (InvalidArgumentException e) { die (e.getMessage()); }
catch (Exception e)                { die (e); }
```

For me this is the most readable way. It gets only cluttered when people try to write complete novels into exception names.

```
catch (CanNotPayAttentionToThatManBehindTheCurtainThrowableRuntimeExceptionWithMessageAndCouseContainItselfAnotherCourseAndMessage e) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that "in most cases" you should be doing more than just printing or logging the stack trace. This means you are swallowing an exception, which is not generally a good practice. At the least, if you cannot gracefully recover from the exception, you should log and rethrow it in case code higher up the stack can.

That said, I don't think there is really an answer to your question beyond "that's just how they designed it".

Answer (score 0):

Probably inherited from C++. No idea why C++ did that. See my thoughts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254595/how-do-you-use-the-return/6255489#6255489

It's also worth noting that `{}` makes grammar simpler, i.e. makes language designer's life easier. The `if` statement is a good example - the convenience you like does not come cheaply.

Because of the ambiguity like

```
if(c1) if(c2) A; else B;

interpretation 1 
if(c1)
    if(c2) 
        A;
    else 
        B;

interpretation 2 
if(c1)
    if(c2) 
        A;
else 
    B;
```

The grammar of `if` has to be tweaked to resolve the ambiguity. Suppose `block` is required instead of arbitrary `statement`, the grammar would be much simpler because of the presence of `{}`.

So they were probabaly just feeling lazy.

Comment: This is not an argument for the programmer, because when the programmer writes down his code the language is already designed, the grammar is already written, and the compiler generator has already done his job.