# Plus minus button adjustment using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Two things:

1. Adjusting the plus minus button so that when it reaches its min and max range, the corresponding button is disabled (and apply and remove CSS - active is bold, inactive normal).
2. Output the quantity in a different div. Also club the diff items.

For example:

I got three quantities displayed -

1. Chocolate, Vanilla, Dark Current
2. Chocolate minimum quantity is 1, the other two is 0 and the maximum quantity for all is 6. The default is 1 chocolate. It has to be there.

**But the total quantity should not exceed 6.** Also, in the external div, show
Items - 1 chocolate

Now when you change the chocolate quantity to 2, ext div should show (note the plural)
Items - 2 chocolates

Now when you select dark current (1 q)
Items - 2 chocolates, 1 dark current

If you also select vanilla(1 q), now the div should show
Items - 4 goodies

That means the external "div" displays information of only 2 items separately. If more, it clubs and generalizes the items, but shows the total quantity.

Now if you reduce dark current, the div should show
Items - 2 chocolates, 1 vanilla

**My issues -**

1. For chocolate, minus button not honoring min quantity, sometimes shows zero.
2. Implementing dynamic information in an external div (for some reason, dark current does not increment in the fiddle).

Link - http://jsfiddle.net/YfgrK/1/

```
// Increment
if(defaultInp.val() < jQuery(defaultInp).data('max'))

    //If I put "var _val = " here
    //I get - [object Object] Chocolate. Why?
    $('input[name = ' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);

    //Save for display in ext div
    var _val = currentVal + 1;

    //Show in div
    $(".count-pax").text(_val + ' ' + fieldName);
    console.log(currentVal);

    //Disable button
    if(defaultInp.val() == jQuery(defaultInp).data('max'))
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(".paxminus").removeAttr("disabled");
} 
else {
    //Otherwise put a 0 there
    $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
```

Next

```
// Decrement one
if(defaultInp.val() > minVal)

    //If I put "var _val = " here
    //I get - [object Object] Chocolate. Why?
    $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);

    //Save for display in ext div
    var _val = currentVal - 1;

    //Show in div
    $(".count-pax").text(_val + ' ' + fieldName);

    //Disable button
    if(defaultInp.val() == jQuery(defaultInp).data('min'))
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(".paxplus").removeAttr("disabled");
} 
else {
    //Otherwise put a 0 there
    $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
```

Comment: The original indentation indicated that "$(".paxminus").removeAttr("disabled");" and "$(".paxplus").removeAttr("disabled");" are in an 'if' clause. That is not the case. What is the intent?

Comment: They are in the if statement. Those buttons need to be enabled/disabled accordingly when the input range is reached. Only the first button, Chocolate, not abiding when in lowest range. It is still clickable, though it happens when u increase using other buttons!

Comment: They are not in an 'if' clause according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117873/do-if-statements-in-javascript-require-curly-braces/7117939#7117939).

Comment: yup now i get it. thnx for that. but it seemed that way it is working as i want, though the chocolate button has the problem! if i include in brackets, things wont work that great? how can i improve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things organized, you could create a separate function just to update the total value info. In this function, go over the `<li>`'s, appending to a text our final count on each element that has a value greater than "0".

Call this function at the end of your click events.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YfgrK/4/

```
function UpdateCount() {
    var text = "";
    $("#myform li").each(function() {
        var field = $(this).find("input[field]").attr("field");
        var val = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();
        if(parseInt(val) > 0) {
            text += (text == "" ? "" : ", ") + val + " " + field;
        }
    });
    $(".count-pax").text(text);
}
```

**EDIT**

Just to explain the inline text checking to add a comma, it's the same of doing this:

```
if(text != "")
    text += ", ";
text += val + " " + field;
```

Comment: hi i didnt get the line after parseInt.

Comment: It's just an inline way of checking if the text is no longer empty, to add a comma. See the updated andswer.

Comment: Thnx. Now i get it. Now i am trying to figure out how to club those values. I can count the total but still need to figure out to disable further increment of items, after limit, and clubbing if more than two items.