# ScrollTop not working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am currently have a function to reveal images on [this site](http://sinclairblack.co.nz/), if you scroll down on homepage you will see the image being reveals as well as on [this page](http://sinclairblack.co.nz/who-we-are/).

Here's the JS, however the scrollTop part doesn't seem to be working on IE and Firefox, my developer wrote this and I am trying to fix it myself without his help..

```
revealImages: function() {
  var currentScroll = 0;
  var totalScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  var newScroll = $('body').scrollTop();

  $('.image-flip').each(function() {
    if(newScroll + $(window).height() >= $(this).offset().top + 200 && currentScroll < newScroll) $(this).addClass('flipped');
  });

  currentScroll = newScroll;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scrolltop firefox not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776544/jquery-scrolltop-firefox-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found some bugs in your code.

```js
var newScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
```

replace on

```js
var newScroll = $('html, body').scrollTop();
```

FF return always 0 in your case.

Another bug is in your if statement. You forgot {}

This is a fix code

```js
revealImages: function() {
  var currentScroll = 0;
  var totalScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  var newScroll = $('html, body').scrollTop();

  $('.image-flip').each(function() {
    if( ( newScroll + $(window).height() ) >= ( $(this).offset().top + 200 ) && ( currentScroll < newScroll ) ){
     $(this).addClass('flipped'); 
    }
  });

  currentScroll = newScroll;
}
```

Comment: Re if statement: braces not required in this instance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117873/do-if-statements-in-javascript-require-curly-braces