# How to loop through multiple images for displaying in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, for-loop, modal-dialog

I am trying to display multiple (approximately 10) images in a modal by looping through the each of them. The modal opens after clicking on the link present in a table cell, but nothing shows in the modal.

When I display only 1 image, then it gets displayed in modal. I am using React.js for the first time. Please help me with the solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    }, {
        Header: 'Screenshot',
        accessor: 'screenshot',
        maxWidth: 100,
        Cell: row => {
            if (row.original.screenshot)
                var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < row.original.screenshot.length; i++) {
                array.push = <img src={"data:image/png;base64," + row.original.screenshot[i]} />
            }
            var Image = array.join('');
            return <a onClick={() => {
                this.setState({
                    screenShotModalOpen: true,
                    screenShotImage:
                        <div>
                            {Image}
                        </div>
                })
                    href={'javascript:void(0)'}>View</a>

            }}
        },
    }],
}]
```

Comment: please provide your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

For your `if` statement in `line 169`, add curly braces. If you have multiple lines in your `if` statement, then curly braces are required. [Do 'if' statements in JavaScript require curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117873/do-if-statements-in-javascript-require-curly-braces)