# Align column elements horizontally between other column elements with the same structure that displayed in a row

Tags: css

I want to align elements with different sizes of my column horizontally between items from other columns (based on bigger one)
The text is a dynamic value. It can feet a dynamic number of rows.

```css
p,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 60px;
}

.item {
  width: 33.3%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 40px;
}

.item img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  align-self: center;
}

.item h6 {
  background: blue;
}

.item p {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <h6>Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title</h6>
    <p>
      Nunc nonummy metus. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Nunc nonummy metus. Phasellus volutpat,
      metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Nam pretium turpis et arcu.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <h6>Some Title Some</h6>
    <p>
      Nunc nonummy metus. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Nam pretium turpis et arcu.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <h6>Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title Some Title</h6>
    <p>
      Nunc nonummy metus. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Nam pretium turpis et arcu.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot Before:
[image]

Screenshot After:
[image]

Comment: The question has a css tag only. Are you open to a JS/jQuery answer? If so check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922889/use-jquery-to-get-largest-height-value-of-children-then-apply-that-height-value

Comment: @RiccardoLV I'm interested just in the CSS solution. Your URL doesn't solve my problem even with the JS/JQuery. I can make each column's height equal to each others just with CSS. But my problem is a little bit another.

Comment: You're looking for the [`subgrid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) property-value (to be used on `grid-template-columns`/`grid-template-rows`); unfortunately this is only supported in Firefox and Safari (at the time of writing, and Chrome doesn't seem to have any impetus to do anything with it, yet). Here's [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/08rdyf9w/1/), so you can see - in Firefox or Safari - how it might be used once it's more widely available.

Comment: As an aside, though, it would probably help your question if it was easier for those answering to reproduce your problem; can you put together some basic `Lorem ipsum` HTML that we can work with, in order to minimise our workload when we want to help?

Comment: @AndrewKovalchuk Indeed "my" url CAN solve your problem: just assign the same class to the elements with the blu border in your pictures and then run the jQuery code you find there with that class in place of "div.columns". But since you're looking for a CSS only solution I wish someone will make you happy with that :-)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, I've already added the initial code.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `display: flex`

If you modify your HTML so you nest the blue and green text in a separate div, the CSS for said div would look something like this:

```
.nested_div_class{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

or you could use `display: grid`, with the size of every grid cell pre-set