# jQuery / Javascript: iterate over an array to select divs from the array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a series of divs on my page and am having trouble selecting each div containing a specific string when the string is kept in an array. For example, if the array = ['foo', 'qux'], I would like to be able to select the div containing 'foo', and the div containing 'qux'.

```
<div class="word word1">foo</div>
<div class="word word2">bar</div>
<div class="word word3">baz</div>
<div class="word word4">qux</div>
```

The script

```
array =  ['foo', 'qux'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array_text = array[i];
  alert( $( "div:contains(array_text)" ).text() );
}
```

I have also used this script without success:

```
correct_matches =  ['foo', 'qux'];
$.each(correct_matches, function(index, value){
  alert( $( "div:contains(value)" ).text() );
  }
);
```

I am using the alert only to ascertain whether or not the $( "div:contains(array_text)") selector is working properly. The selector is where I am running into problems: $( "div:contains('bar')" ) works as expected. Once I use the array_text variable, I get an alert with an empty string. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You need to escape the selector to include a variable, otherwise it's just looking for `contains "value"` not the variable `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LuZuz/)**.

You were testing if the text `array_text` was contained by the `div`.

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal, but it works.

jQuery version:

```
$(function () {

    var array = ['baz', 'qux'];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array_text = array[i];
        $('div').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == array_text) {
                alert(array[i]);
                // do more stuff with $(this) (which is the div)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted, and more, because now I can do more stuff with $(this), which is my next step, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array =  ['foo', 'qux'];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".word"); // get all elements of class word

for(var i =0;i <array   .length;i++ ) // first loop for your array
for(var ii=0;ii<elements.length;ii++) // second loop for the elements in the collection
if(array[i] == elements[ii].innerHTML){ // check for matches
  elements[ii]; // this is the handle to the html element
}
```

Run through both collections and check when there is a match between the 2 collections.

Comment: Simple as 2 syntax errors and some unexplained code? No way!

Comment: Just fixed it. Sorry bit quick on the reply button

Comment: You still haven't explained your code. That's critical for a good answer

Comment: added comment for every line

Comment: maybe you should indent your code and using curly braces `{}` is [good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript).

Comment: I would say programmers would know what rules apply. But seeing the nature of this question suggests easy confusion. Which i probably why this was not accepted as the answer.