# Correct JavaScript IF Else Syntax

Tags: javascript

I am updating an existing JavaScript application.  Part of this update involves formatting things better and cleaning up code.

Right now this is one of the Functions which uses `if()` and `else`  statements without all the correct brackets in place... I personbally hate it when people do this shorthand method and even more so when they mix it and use it sometimes and not others.  THat is the case in this example code below.

```
this.setFlags = function() {
    if (document.documentElement)
        this.dataCode = 3;
    else
    if (document.body && typeof document.body.scrollTop != 'undefined')
        this.dataCode = 2;
    else
    if (this.e && this.e.pageX != 'undefined')
        this.dataCode = 1;

    this.initialised = true;
}
```

I honestly do not know how to correctly add the brackets to this function, below is what I have but I am thinking it might not be correct.  Can a JavaScript expert let me know?

```
this.setFlags = function() {
    if (document.documentElement){
        this.dataCode = 3;
    }else{
        if (document.body && typeof document.body.scrollTop != 'undefined'){
            this.dataCode = 2;
        }else{
            if (this.e && this.e.pageX != 'undefined'){
                this.dataCode = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    this.initialised = true;
}
```

Comment: It's correct. Congrats on adding the brackets correctly. Is that your only question?

Comment: Both are fine, when you have to write just one line in `if` statement, there is no need to put `{}`.

Comment: not using {} on single line if cases/conditions is often considered a bad practice, because errors can hide in plain sight if you have poor indentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I share your dislike of unbracketed `if/else` statements. Your bracketing seems correct to me. However, there's a simpler way that's equivalent:

```
this.setFlags = function() {
    if (document.documentElement) {
        this.dataCode = 3;
    } else if (document.body && typeof document.body.scrollTop != 'undefined') {
        this.dataCode = 2;
    } else if (this.e && this.e.pageX != 'undefined') {
        this.dataCode = 1;
    }

    this.initialised = true;
}
```

As Dave Chen points out in a comment, because of the simplicity and parallelism of the `if/else` branches—they all assign a value to `this.dataCode`—you could also use nested ternary operators:

```
this.setFlags = function() {
    this.dataCode = document.documentElement                           ? 3
                  : document.body
                      && typeof document.body.scrollTop != 'undefined' ? 2
                  : this.e && this.e.pageX != 'undefined'              ? 1
                  :                                                      this.dataCode;

    this.initialised = true;
}
```

The advantage of this is that it is clearer that all the conditions are simply determining which value to assign to `this.dataCode`. The disadvantage (a big one, in my opinion) is that unless the nested ternary operators are formatted in a careful way (such as what I did here), it's basically impossible to get any sense of what's going on without carefully studying the expression. Unfortunately, most JavaScript code formatters that I'm familiar with do a very poor job of formatting such expressions (or preserving such formatting). (Interestingly, several Perl formatters that I've used do a wonderful job of this. But this isn't Perl.)

Comment: You could also use ternary, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking. The question isn't, "How can I make this code better?".

Comment: @DaveChen - Yes, that's another possibility. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: It's great, I know it was a super basic question but the way it was formatted it wasn't all that clear to me, thanks and yes improvements are always welcome!

Comment: @DaveChen - Well, I take that back. There's no unconditional `else` case so there is no value to use as the last operand in a compound ternary expression (when all three `if` tests fail).

Comment: No, because you could just set it to itself. Ternary is ugly sometimes -- but always works. `ex. this.dataCode == whatever ? set value : this.dataCode`

Comment: Sadly if I would of realized the `else if` was an actual `else if` I would of never posted this question but you can see how the `else if` in the original is all on separate lines so it just looked funky to me I guess.  Now that i'm looking at them as `else if` it actually makes more sense i feel silly just not use to seeing an `if else` without brackets

Comment: @DaveChen - Right you are again. It's too late at night for me to be posting on SO. I've now added your suggestion.

Comment: @TedHopp Can that be my excuse as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the updates, it's nice to see it done different ways

Answer (score 1):

It's correct but you can make it neater:

```
this.setFlags = function() {
  if (document.documentElement) {
    this.dataCode = 3;
  } else if (document.body && typeof document.body.scrollTop != 'undefined') {
    this.dataCode = 2;
  } else if (this.e && this.e.pageX != 'undefined') {
    this.dataCode = 1;
  }

 this.initialized = true;
};
```

oh this is already posted