# If/else statement with no curly brackets javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've searched and I can't find a question already like this. However, why does this code work?

```
    this.askTeller = function(pass) {
     if (pass == 1234) return bankBalance;
     else return "Wrong password.";
   };
```

Shouldn't it be like

```
this.askTeller = function(pass) {
if (pass == 1234) {
return bankBalance;
}
else {
return "Wrong password.";
};
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/4797286/552116

Answer (score 10):

> Shouldn't it be like

Arguably, it should be:

```
this.askTeller = function(pass) {
  if (pass == 1234) return bankBalance;
  return "Wrong password.";
};
```

or

```
this.askTeller = function(pass) {
  return pass == 1234 ? bankBalance : "Wrong password.";
};
```

E.g., there's no point to the `else` at all.

But getting to your point about `{}`: They're optional. Control-flow structures like `if` (and `while`, and `for`, etc.) are connected to the **one** statement that follows them; if you want to have them connected to more than one statement, you use the *block statement* (`{...}`) to do that.

Many, many, many people always use the block statement even when they could get away with not using it, both for clarity and to make it easier to add a second thing into the block.

Answer (score 6):

in Javascript the curly brackets are optional for `if/else` when you have only one statement after to execute. Note that if you will execute multiple stuff after then you will need to include the `{/}` or only the first statement will be applied to the condition

Answer (score 2):

You can drop curly braces for nearly all block-scoped structures (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc).  The only exception (heh) I've ran into where this isn't the case is with `try` and `catch`.

If you don't include curly braces, only the first statement after the block will be executed.

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");

for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) out.innerHTML += i;

if (out.innerHTML === "012345") out.innerHTML += " success!";
```

```html
<textarea id="out"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

brackets are optional for if statement

Comment: After a if or loop (for, while) you can omit the curly braces ONLY if you have only one statement after it