# Controlling wrap and unwrap methods in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the demo code below. How can I use jQuery in these ways?:

1- Wrap the `p` only if it has not already wrapped with `.check-wrap-sapn`

and

2- Unwrap *only* `.check-wrap-sapn` and not any other parent?

What is happening now jQuery wraps the `p` element with `.check-wrap-sapn` as long as users clicks on `#wrap` and removes all parents of  `p` even if there is not any wrapper called  `.check-wrap-sapn`

```js
$("#wrap").on("click", function() {
  $("p").wrap("<div class='check-wrap-sapn'></div>");
});

$("#unwrap").on("click", function() {
  $("p").unwrap("<div class='check-wrap-sapn'></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <p>This is for Wrapping</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="wrap">Wrap</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="unwrap">Un Wrap</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get it's parent using **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** and check it's `.check-wrap-sapn` or not using **[`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)**

```js
var $p = $("p");

$("#wrap").on("click", function() {
  if ($p.parent().is(':not(.check-wrap-sapn)'))
    $p.wrap("<div class='check-wrap-sapn'></div>");
});

$("#unwrap").on("click", function() {
  if ($p.parent().is('.check-wrap-sapn'))
    $p.unwrap("<div class='check-wrap-sapn'></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <p>This is for Wrapping</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="wrap">Wrap</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="unwrap">Un Wrap</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav C Balan but why you are not using `{ }` after the if statement?

Comment: @Suffii : there is only one line of code to execute... so it's optional....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript

Comment: @Suffii : glad to help :)