# jQuery hasClass Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: jquery

I got this error in console log but can't determine what's wrong. I would like to hide an element when the button is collapsed

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
if(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed") 
    $(".country-flags-container").hide();
else   
    $(".country-flags-container").show();
)}
```

I appreciate your help for my learnings.

Comment: For syntax errors in JavaScript, it's simple to use [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) which will tell you the line numbers of the syntax errors.

Comment: You should add one more ) for if statement like if(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed") )

Comment: There is only one syntax error in code which is in last.... i.e   
}) replaced by )}...so why all of giving same type answers...
@ Kobe Brayan You can use a good text editor(like sublime) for avoiding syntax errors like this...()

Comment: I will try to use Sublime. I currently using notepad++ @AbhishekMishra

Comment: Sounds good :) @KobeBryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one :

```
   $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
    if((".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")) // missing () for if statement
        $(".country-flags-container").hide();
    else   
        $(".country-flags-container").show();
    });// this was the issue
```

Good luck

Comment: it's not the only issue. spot the other and my downvote becomes an upvote.

Comment: I gave you the upvote anyway, your answer combined with the other answers will get the op to solve it.

- edit - you found it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @lazy_coder! Appreciated it a lot!

Comment: @KobeBryan can you please accept the answer so he gets the points?

Answer (score 1):

You are using this code :

```
if(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")
```

and

```
".navbar-toggle"
```

is not a selector, also if you use this :

```
$(".navbar-toggle")
```

it return an array of elements having class 'navbar-toggle'

try this :

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
if( $(this).hasClass("collapsed") )
    $(".country-flags-container").hide();
else   
    $(".country-flags-container").show();
)}
```

also you have to think about removing the "collapsed" class after checking it, it's a flag ;)

Comment: At the very least take the time to explain what the problem was, and the changes you made.

Comment: sorry, i changed :
if(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed") 
by
if( $(this).hasClass("collapsed") )

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the explanation where it's likely to be read., which also allows code to be readable and offers more space for a coherent, formatted presentation.

Comment: Thank you so much @kanzari and @DavidThomas!

Comment: @Kobe, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing brackets for if condition. You also missed `$` from `(".navbar-toggle")`. This should be `$(".navbar-toggle")`. Please try the following:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
   if($(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")){ 
      $(".country-flags-container").hide();
   }
   else{   
      $(".country-flags-container").show();
   }
});
```

You can replace `$(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")` by the following as well:

```
$(this).hasClass("collapsed")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript

so only the missing ) is an error.

Comment: Thank you so much @Muhammad Qasim! Appreciated it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
   if(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")) 
    $(".country-flags-container").hide();
  else   
    $(".country-flags-container").show();
  )}
```

Try this You miss the ) for if condition

Comment: Thank you so much @Abi! Appreciated it a lot!