# javascript validation in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

instantly alert when user break validation, but here which script in 1 problem, when i click input textfield than alert msg even i didn't enter any value.

```js
<script>
        function validation(){
            var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
            if (rate == "" || rate.length<5);
            alert("it is wrong value");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::label('rate', 'Traded Rate:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('rate', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'onclick'=>'return validation()'])!!}
            </div>
```

Comment: your if statement has no "body" { }. So alert is called every time, even if the if is false.

Comment: @physi In Javascript, brackets are not required for single-line if statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript for more info.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: yes but then the trailing ";" is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @physi Ignoring my deleted comment, yes, semicolon does seem to be an issue here.

Comment: So what can i do for that? -@physi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation appears to be triggered since you have set `onclick` on the input tag. Try replacing `onclick` into `oninput` so that the function will be called when you start to input something in the input field. Also, consider @physi's comment by modifying your function into the code below:

```
function validation(){
    var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
    if (rate == "" || rate.length<5){
      alert("it is wrong value");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but its giving me a same result -@undrftd

Comment: Do you got it my question? when i feel textfield wrong value after giving me a msg, but it alert before feel value

Comment: Do you mean it will validate only when you try to input in the field? Did you already change onlick to oninput?