# Setting text colour with jQuery based on a class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having trouble doing something that seems like it should be very simple.  I want to simply set the text colour to red if the value is less than zero.

So in this first function I get the value, and upon "success" I want to set the colour to red if the balance < 0.  Simple.

```
function getTimeBankBalance(staffid){

  if(staffid == undefined){
    var staffid = $('#staffid').val();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'get-timebankbalance.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      cache: false,
      staffid: staffid
    },
    success: function(balance) {
      $('.timebankbalance').html(roundToTwo(balance) + " Hours");
      if(balance < 0) $('.timebankbalance.').css('color','red');
    },
    error: function(){
      genericPrompt("Error","Unable to calculate staff time bank balance","errormessage-inline");
    },
  });
}
```

The reason I'm using a class selector is because I have two places where the balance is displayed.

Anyway the above function is called when the page has finished loading.

```
$(function(){
  getTimeBankBalance();
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  So I thought maybe it was a timing issue, and it appears to be because when I pause the code execution in the debugger the text turns red.  Without the debugger it stays black.

So then I tried moving the code into a separate function

```
function setBalanceColour(balance){
  if(balance < 0){
    $('.timebankbalance.').css('color','red');
  }
}
```

And delaying that function call by a few seconds...

```
 setTimeout(setBalanceColour(balance),5000);
```

That didn't help either.  So what's going on here?  Why won't it change the colour?

Comment: Is the `$('.timebankbalance').html(...)` part working?

Comment: Just having a quick look at your code I noticed you have an extra period when you call your class here `$('.timebankbalance.')`

Comment: Yes, that's working perfectly fine.

Comment: That's it!  crazymatt, you just saved me a headache.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes.  It's amazing what we don't see when we stare at something too long.

Comment: @Vincent haha it happens to me all the time. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like we discussed in the comments there is an extra period `.` in `$('.timebankbalance.')`

So this line:

```
if(balance < 0) $('.timebankbalance.').css('color','red');
```

would look like:

```
if(balance < 0) $('.timebankbalance').css('color','red');
```

Comment: Are you not missing curly braces?

Comment: @SleekGeek the code in my answer is a copy of OP code with the period removed. But in JS you can do one line `if` statments. [You can read about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript).