# Please What is Wrong with This Javascript Calculator?

Tags: javascript

Trying to calculate this but not working for me.
Is there any issue with the **daya** variable?
The whole code  -

```js
function change_payment() {
  var amount = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
  var plan = $("#select-payment").val();
  var percent = 5.7;
  var daya = 5;
  if(plan == "1")
  percent = 2.5;
  daya = 5;
  else if(plan == "2")
  percent = 3;
  daya = 6;
  console.log(amount);
  var daily = ((amount/100)*percent).toFixed(1);
  var total = (daily*daya).toFixed(1);
  $("#daily").html(daily);
  $("#total").html(total);
}
```

Comment: Use brackets for your if statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are braces necessary in one-line statements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You miss brackets in your statement.

```js
if (plan == "1")
percent = 2.5;
daya = 5;
```

is not equal to:

```js
if (plan == "1") {
  percent = 2.5;
  daya = 5;
}
```

but is equal to:

```js
if (plan == "1") {
  percent = 2.5;
}

daya = 5;
```

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else.