# else if not working in KeyCode events javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, solid

I am trying to make me character moving left and up and I think  `jump()` and `slideLeft()`
functions are working properly and the problem is in the `controller(e)` function (`else if (e.KeyCode===37)`) . The first function is avaible but it isn't able to acces the second conditon function. Also, I would want to make the grid solid after I will make an `slideRight()` similar function ,so if my character is jumping on it, the platform would sustain the square . Has anyone any ideea for either of my questions ?

Code snippet:

```js
var square = document.querySelector('.square');
var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
var bottom = 0;
let isJumping = false;
let isGoingLeft = false;
var newBottom;
let left = 0;
let leftTimerId;


function jump() {
  if (isJumping) return
  let timerUpId = setInterval(function() {
    if (bottom > 250) {
      clearInterval(timerUpId);

      let timerDownId = setInterval(function() {
        if (bottom < 0) {
          clearInterval(timerDownId);
          isJumping = false;
        }
        bottom -= 5;
        square.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
      }, 20)
    }
    isJumping = true;
    bottom += 30;
    square.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
  }, 20)
}

function slideLeft() {
  console.log('da');
  isGoingLeft = true;
  leftTimerId = setInterval(function() {
    left -= 5;
    square.style.left = left + 'px';
  }, 20)
}

function controller(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32)
    jump();
  else if (e.KeyCode === 37)
    slideLeft();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', controller);
```

```css
.grid {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 150px;
}

`
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: what is `32` and `37` keyboard keys ?

Comment: have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#navigation_keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
There is a typo:
The second time you've written **K**eyCode

```
function controller(e) {
    if(e.keyCode===32) {
        jump();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode===37) {
        slideLeft();
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what you mean by the second part of your question. If you want a character to have the ability to jump on a square, you'll have to implement a collision detection. Something like this:

```
if ( isNotOnGround() ) { 
    fall() 
}
```

Comment: Nope, the brackets are optional when only a single statement is executed when the condition passes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I didn't know that..
However there's a typo in your code, see my edit.

Comment: Curly brace optional but then no semi-colon which terminates the statement
Not having braces to me makes the code less readable
https://stackoverflow.com/q/4797286/125981