# Is there a way to shorten multiple || (or) in a single function?

Tags: javascript, function, logic

I have this function. It works fine. Is there a way to shorten the logic though?

```
function doNotDuplicateRandomIndex() {
  if (randomIndex === 0 || randomIndex === 1 || randomIndex === 2 || randomIndex ===3) {
    createRandomIndex();
  }
}
```

I haven't tried anything else, simply because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Less than (`<`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than) operator. You're welcome.

```js
function doNotDuplicateRandomIndex() {
  if (randomIndex < 4) {
    createRandomIndex();
  }
}
```

In fact, this can be even shorter by removing the brackets from the [`if...else` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

See: [Are braces necessary in one-line statements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797293/22152755)

```js
function doNotDuplicateRandomIndex() {
  if (randomIndex < 4) createRandomIndex();
}
```

Insane, we can make the whole function even shorter by converting it to an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

The [`if...else` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) is replaced with a [Logical AND (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator.

```js
const doNotDuplicateRandomIndex = () => randomIndex < 4 && createRandomIndex();
```

Nice answer by [XMehdi01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14529779/xmehdi01), the same concept can be converted to an arrow function expression too.

```js
const doNotDuplicateRandomIndex = () => [0, 1, 2, 3].includes(randomIndex) && createRandomIndex();
```

Comment: If the index could have negative values (as in `array.at(-1)`, for example), `<` would be unsuitable.

Comment: Quite true, I've to admit, but that's something that's not included in the question, and I think I don't have to predict the future of what the OP is going to do with the function later, am I wrong? Anyway, +1 @InSync

Comment: If I were to worry about specific negative values, I’d go with .include. But since I am not worried about that, this is certainly the best answer. Especially boiling it down to one line. I’m impressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
function doNotDuplicateRandomIndex() {
  if ([0,1,2,3].includes(randomIndex)){
    createRandomIndex();
  }
}
```

Comment: I love this answer because .includes could be used for so much. I can’t mark it as the best answer though, simply because I think the <4 logic is easier to edit if I need to check for numbers 1-7 or something else. The precision of .includes is super useful though, and I’ll likely use that in a lot of places. Thanks!

Comment: My answer `.includes()` could handle the case where you want to verify numbers that are not consecutive like `1, 10, 8`, you can't do that with  logic of `<N` !?

Answer (score 2):

I like the other answer, but in your case I think you could use an object or map to check whether an `id` is used:

```
const usedIds = {};
usedIds['1234-1234'] = true;

function doNotDuplicateRandomIndex() {
  if (typeof usedIds[id] === 'undefined') {
    createRandomIndex();
  }
}
```

you could also use [Map.prototype.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)