# fileFilter optinon in multer causing request.file to be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want Multer allows just photo to be uploaded but it doesn't work and gives request.file = undefined and at the same time the file.mimetype = image/jpeg which is correct

Here is a clip from Postman:
[image]

I checked the headers also and it contains `Content-Type = multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`

then I tried and removed `fileFilter: multerFilter` configurations from Multer and the surprise that everything worked fine without any single problem. Here is the related code:

```
const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

// 2) Creating a multer filter (to test if the uploaded file is really an image):
const multerFilter = (request, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) cb(null, true);
  cb(new AppError(400, `The only accepted files are images, please select an image ${request.file} file tyep: ${file.mimetype}`), false);
};

const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage, fileFilter: multerFilter });

exports.updateMyPhoto = upload.single("photo");
```

Please help me find what's wrong with my fileFilter configuration

UPDATE:

I switched between the two conditions inside `multerFilter` and the program is working perfectly now. the new code:

```
const multerFilter = (request, file, cb) => {
  if (!file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) cb(new AppError(400, `The only accepted files are images, please select an image ${request.file} file tyep: ${file.mimetype}`), false);
  cb(null, true);
  };
```

I still don't know the reason for this behaviour so I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your callback function `cb` with `return` keyword. Otherwise after the first callback function call, your code will continute and eventually the second callback function will be called and this will cause this confusing problem to be occur. To solve this update your code using `return` keyword:

```js
const multerFilter = (request, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) return cb(null, true);
  return cb(new AppError(400, `The only accepted files are images, please select an image ${request.file} file tyep: ${file.mimetype}`), false);
};
```

To understand how your current implementation behaves, run the following code snippet and see the outputs.

```js
const filterCheckWithoutReturnKeyword = (number, callback) => {
  if(number > 10) callback('Number is greater than 10!');
  callback('Number is less than 10!');
};

const filterCheckWithReturnKeyword = (number, callback) => {
  if(number > 10) return callback('Number is greater than 10!');
  return callback('Number is less than 10!');
};

const callbackFn = (message) => console.log(message);

filterCheckWithoutReturnKeyword(5, callbackFn);
filterCheckWithoutReturnKeyword(15, callbackFn);

// Seperator log
console.log('---------------');

filterCheckWithReturnKeyword(5, callbackFn);
filterCheckWithReturnKeyword(15, callbackFn);
```

Comment: I can't believe that I've missed the `return` keyword !! what a silly mistake.
Your answer helped me a lot, thank you very much

Comment: @Marya you are welcome! We do silly mistakes from time to time. Have a good one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first set of code does work... it just doesn't work the way you expect. You think you are coding an `if/else` but it looks like you are just calling the callback (`cb`) twice. That means the second callback will always execute.

There is a lot of debate about whether or not to include curly braces in your code and there are arguments for both, but if you want to avoid one source of bugs then always include curly braces. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416541/21972629) answer explains it best.

Try to change your first code to this:

```
const multerFilter = (request, file, cb) => {
   if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")){
      cb(null, true);
   } else{
      cb(new AppError(400, `The only accepted files are images, please 
   select an image ${request.file} file tyep: ${file.mimetype}`), false);
   }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It is a habit of mine to use an if() block with no curly braces when it has just one statement, I believe this way makes my code cleaner although it has its risks

Comment: Totally valid approach. I try to stay unopinionated and stick to solving the problem. The multer [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) for `fileFilter` are pretty unopinionated too and leave the implementation up to you too. Good luck with your project.