# JavaScript shorthand math on same line for defining CSS value

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the shorthand to assign a CSS style and add the pixels on the same line? The following doesn't work though it should be exceptionally clear what I'm trying to do:

```
header.style.top = (h + 100)+px;
```

Comment: I think the question isn't clear enough ? what you are doing and what you want ? and provide some more code please

Comment: Just add: var px = "px";  before that line and it's good. ;)

Comment: were you able to solve this? Please let me know if my suggestion helped you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`px` is not defined. I believe you are intending to concat a string. Observe the following...

```
header.style.top = (h + 100) + 'px';
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/4r1kfquk/) - simplified demo

Comment: It was late Friday evening and the left brain doesn't function well after hours of coding. It was a two-part mistake on my end; yeah there was no `px` object, I forgot to put quotes to make it a string. I also made another mistake though unrelated to the code here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
header.style.top = (h + 100) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to specify the `px` value. It defaults to `pixels`

checkout this question: [Using Javascript to add width to a HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750835/using-javascript-to-add-width-to-a-html-element)

As found here http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle  they say to enclose the px in brackets `'px'`. Like the above answers.