# javascript and c++ double numbers 0.0

Tags: javascript, c++, numbers

I am trying to convert some code from C++ to JavaScript but I am very confused with `ints`, `doubles`, `NaN` and parsing floats. I think!?

```
Z = T - 14 - (1);
while (Z <= T)
{
    var S1 = 0.0;
    for (var C = 0; C <= P - 1; C++)
    {
        if (V[Z + C] !== undefined)
        {
            skip = 0;
            S1 = S1 + (V[Z + C] + V[Z + C]) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            skip = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log('S1: ' + S1);
    Z++;
}
```

`S1` is now always `NaN` how do I stop this? (something to do with `typeof`?)

On a good note: I've got the `V=[]` part to work and that uses doubles and am working on the undefined part (messy fix) so that is some good progress.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the edit but, before you have a go at someone else look first at your self mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218756/javascript-braces-on-new-line-or-not see the answer in that post about Douglas Crockford. And this is a question and answer forum not a question and insult forum.

Comment: Could you post the original C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an operation involving `floats` fails, `NaN` is the resulting value. `NaN` has an interesting property: operating with `NaN` always results in `NaN`.

This means that as soon as one of your variables holds `NaN`, the value will propagate with all future operations.

`console.log` your floats, and detect the moment in which one becomes `NaN`. My bet is in `(V[Z + C] + V[Z + C])`.