# Display price between given dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the structure and data of my price

if number is between 0 and 2000 (or in other word the number is less then 2000) - then must appear tax "20"
if number is between 2001 and 5000 - then must appear tax 35

```
Price:<input type=text name=price><br>
Tax: <input type=text name=tax>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is: "Can you do my work for me pls?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add labels for your inputs, they are linked to the input with ids

```
<label for="priceInput">Price:</label><input id="priceInput" type=text name=price><br>
<label for="taxInput">Tax:</label><input id="taxInput" type=text name=tax>
```

And in your jquery:

```
//Function is executed when the priceInput is changed, so when you enter a value
$("#priceInput").change(function(){
    //Test if the value of the input is < 2000 and >0
    if (($( "#priceInput" ).val()<2000) && ($("#priceInput").val()>0)) {
        //Set the value of the tax input to 20
        $("#taxInput").val(20)
    }
    //test if tyhe value is >2000 and <5000
    else if(($( "#priceInput" ).val()<5000) && ($("#priceInput").val()>2000)){
        $("#taxInput").val(35)
    }
    else{
        $("#taxInput").val("")
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/358RM/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/358RM/ not working(

Comment: I've edited me post, just make a change event listener and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
function setPrice()
{ 
    if ($('[name=price]').val() < 2000)
    {
        $('[name=tax]').val(20);
    }
    else
    {
        $('[name=tax]').val(35);
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid that expanded style for braces in JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/a/3218860/2375207