# Using a custom auto formatter for VS 2013 "Edit->Format Document"

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, typescript

I want to format a document in a special way, instead of auto formatting:

```
if(...){

}else{

}
```

VS should format it like this:

```
if(...)
{

}
else
{

}
```

So the brackets (`{` and `}`) should be direct under the keywords.

How is that possible?

Comment: There's actually a reason why the usual convention in javascript is to keep braces on the same line, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3218860/62829. From personal experience, changing the editor defaults is a bad idea unless you always work alone, you will get in a checkin war with your colleagues, changing the style of code every time you check it in and making it hard to see the actual code changes in a diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in VS by activating the two checkboxes in Tools > Options... > Text Editor > JavaScript (or whatever formatting you want to customize) > Formatting > New Lines.

[image]