# Factory in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-factory

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the below code factory part ? I get an error message for the third console log. Thanks in advance.

> ```
> fsp.html:95 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
>     angular.js:36Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyModule&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415)
>       at angular.js:36
>       at angular.js:3906
>       at r (angular.js:325)
>       at e (angular.js:3872)
>       at gc (angular.js:3812)
>       at c (angular.js:1444)
>       at fc (angular.js:1459)
>       at Xc (angular.js:1368)
>       at angular.js:21949
>       at HTMLDocument.a (angular.js:2573)
> ```

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MyModule">
 <div ng-controller="MyController">

 </div>
 <script>
    var mod = angular.module('MyModule',[]);
    mod.provider("myProvider",function()
    {
        this.$get = function()
        {
            return "MyValue";
        };
    });
    mod.service("myService",function()
    {
        this.myFunc = function()
        {
            return "MyValueService";
        };
    });
    mod.factory("myFactory",function()
    {
        return
        {
            myFunc :function()
            {
                return "MyValueFactory";
            }
        }
    });
    mod.controller("MyController",function(myProvider,myService,myFactory)
    {
        console.log("MyController-myProvider"+myProvider);
        console.log("MyController-myService"+myService.myFunc());
        console.log("MyController-myFactory"+myFactory.myFunc());
    });
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're falling foul of JavaScript's [ASI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons). Change your factory's return statement to...

```
return { // note the brace is on the same line here
  // and the rest as normal
```

Working example ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/2CquJUcUU005F6CBpnky?p=preview

See also ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218860/283366

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Does it matter only for the return ? I have the parentheses in the next line for service and provider and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do this..

```
 mod.factory('myFactory',function ()
    {
        return {
            myFunc:function () {
              return "MyValueFactory";
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

indent your code likes as that

```
</head>
<body ng-app="MyModule">
 <div ng-controller="MyController">

 </div>
 <script>
    var mod = angular.module('MyModule',[]);
    mod.provider("myProvider",function()
    {
        this.$get = function() {
            return "MyValue";
        };
    });
    mod.service("myService",function()
    {
        this.myFunc = function() {
            return "MyValueService";
        };
    });
    mod.factory("myFactory",function()
    {
        return {
            myFunc :function() {
                return "MyValueFactory";
            }
        }
    });
    mod.controller("MyController",function(myProvider,myService,myFactory)
    {
        console.log("MyController-myProvider"+myProvider);
        console.log("MyController-myService"+myService.myFunc());
        console.log("MyController-myFactory"+myFactory.myFunc());
    });
 </script>
</body>
```